# Firebase 'Observe' called multiple times with Swift on iOS

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

When I start the `observer` on a Firebase database node, I notice that Firebase continues to call the method `observer` even when there is no data change.

Here is my setup:

```
FIRDatabase
    .database()
    .reference(withPath: "test")
    .observe(FIRDataEventType.value, with: { (snapshot) in
            print("Firebase Data Updated");
    }
);
```

When I make **one** change to the Firebase database, the `observer` calls its closure function more than one time.

> Firebase Data Updated
>
> Firebase Data Updated
>
> Firebase Data Updated
>
> Firebase Data Updated
>
> Firebase Data Updated
>
> Firebase Data Updated
>
> Firebase Data Updated
>
> ...

Why does this occur?
How can I stop this from occurring and get only one call to the `observer` after an update?

Comment: Once a listener block is registered, it remains registered even if a user logs out. Are you detaching your listener when the view disappears?

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Yes, but the issue is that when the listener is fired multiple times with only one data update. Shouldn't the listener only fire once when the data is updated?

Comment: Where is this function called in your code?

Comment: Called in appDidLaunchWithOptions

Comment: The code in your question by itself, is fine, and your thought is correct that in the the closure will be called any time there's a change in a child of the test node. There's really not enough additional code to draw a context as to what is happening - it's possible that you've attached another observer to the node or possibly the code that changes the test node is malformed. If you can include more code we may be able to nail it down.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's likely this observer is being registered multiple times. When the user logs out, the listener block that you registered stays registered, such that when the user logs in again, you are registering a second listener.

It is often good practice to capture the `ref` and `handle` of observers, and remove the handles once you're done with them (i.e. when a user logs out). You can do so as such:

```
ref, handle = FIRDatabase
    .database()
    .reference(withPath: "test")
    .observe(FIRDataEventType.value, with: { (snapshot) in
            print("Firebase Data Updated");
    }
);
```

And at sign out:

```
ref.removeObserverWithHandle(handle)
```

Otherwise another possible solution to ensure it is only called once is to use `.observeSingleEvent()` instead of `.observe()`.

Comment: @leonardlooi used  .observeSingleEvent() instead of .observe()  and it saved my project . thanks by heart.!!

Answer (score 0):

```
Swift 4: 
If you want to remove all listeners registered with test node.
    Database.database().reference(withPath: "test").removeAllObservers()

If you want to remove particular listener then you need particular handler for observer. You can use following sample code.
    let ref = Database.database().reference(withPath: "test")
            let handler = ref.observe(.value) { (snapshot) in
            }
            ref.removeObserver(withHandle: handler)
```